# Missing performance-now.map in bower-collide folder

Tags: gruntjs, bower

What could be the reason of this error?

[image]

It doesn't exist before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is trying to load Source Map file for your minified `performance-now.js` file. Why he does that? Well, if you look at `performance-now.js` file you definitely will see the comment like

```
//# sourceMappingURL=performance-now.map
```

This is not an actual error, at least for production, because loading of Source Maps takes a place only when DevTools are open. So you can ignore that.

Read more about [Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).